# Printing ssh output to screen

Tags: ruby

I've been working on a script to remotely run a ruby script on another server using net/ssh and print the output to screen so we can see what's going on and I'm almost there thanks to everybody who has answered my questions here. Thanks!

Right now it prints the output but it also prints the commands, /opt/scripts/test_run.rb and exit, several times to the screen first and then the output of the script. I would like to see the commands run once and output of the script to the screen. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'net/ssh'
require 'pty'

puts "RUNNING TEST"
Net::SSH.start(server, user) do |ssh|
  ssh.open_channel do |channel|
     channel.on_request "exit-status" do |channel, data|
     $exit_status = data.read_long
  end
 channel.request_pty do |channel, data|
   channel.exec("sudo -s")
     channel.on_data do |channel, data|
     puts data
     channel.send_data("/opt/scripts/test_run.rb\n")
     channel.send_data("exit\n")
     end
    end
  end
end
puts "DONE"
puts `sleep 5`
puts " "

puts "END OF TEST"
```